# Is this the correct domain of integration for this double integral, under the following coordinate transformation?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, integral-transforms, integral-domain

Suppose you had the double integral $\iint \limits_{A} \frac{y^{2}}{x^{4}}e^{xy} \ dx \ dy$, where $A$ is the region defined by $x>0, \ y>0$ satisfying $x^{2} \leq y \leq 2x^{2}, \ \frac{1}{x} \leq y \leq \frac{2}{x}$, and the coordinate transformation $u=xy, \ v= \frac{y}{x^{2}}$.

If we express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ we get $x=u^{\frac{1}{3}}v^{-\frac{1}{3}}, \ y=u^{\frac{2}{3}}v$.

Subbing this into the parameters for $A$, we get 
\begin{gather*}
x^{2} \leq y \leq 2x^{2} \Rightarrow 1 \leq v \leq 2 \\ \\ 
\frac{1}{x} \leq y \leq \frac{2}{x} \Rightarrow 1\leq u \leq 2
\end{gather*}

Am I correct in thinking that $\iint \limits_{A} dA = \int_{1}^{2} \int_{1}^{2} du\ dv $?

Comment: If you are asking about the *domain of integration* as in your title, yes it is correct.  If you are asking, is the transformed integral correct, no it isn't.